# What is the numpy equivalent of TensorFlow Xavier initializer for CNN?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.x

I would like to re-create the Xavier initialization in NumPy (using basic functions) in the same way that TensorFlow2 does for CNN. 
Here is how I learned to do Xavier initialization in NumPy:

```
# weights.shape = (2,2)
np.random.seed(0)
nodes_in = 2*2
weights = np.random.rand(2,2) * np.sqrt(1/nodes_in)

>>>array([[0.27440675, 0.35759468],
          [0.30138169, 0.27244159]])
```

This is the way I learned Xavier initialization for the logistic regression model. It seems that for Convolution Neural Network it should be different but I don't know how.

```
initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=0)
tf.Variable(initializer(shape=[2,2],dtype=tf.float32))

>>><tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(2, 2) dtype=float32, numpy=
   array([[-0.7078647 ,  0.50461936],
          [ 0.73500216,  0.6633029 ]], dtype=float32)>
```

I'm confused by the TensorFlow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers/GlorotUniform) when they explain the "fan_in" and "fan_out". I'm guessing this is where the problem is. Can somebody dumb it down for me, please?

Much appreciate it!

*[UPDATE]:*

When I follow the [tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers/GlorotUniform) documentation I still don't come to the same results:

```
# weights.shape = (2,2)
np.random.seed(0)
fan_in = 2*2
fan_out = 2*2
limit = np.sqrt(6/(fan_in + fan_out))
np.random.uniform(-limit,limit,size=(2,2))
>>>array([[0.08454747, 0.37271892],
          [0.17799139, 0.07773995]])
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Using Tensorflow**

```
initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=0)
tf.Variable(initializer(shape=[2,2],dtype=tf.float32))
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(2, 2) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.7078647 ,  0.50461936],
       [ 0.73500216,  0.6633029 ]], dtype=float32)>
```

**Same logic in Numpy**

```
import math
np.random.seed(0)
scale = 1/max(1., (2+2)/2.)
limit = math.sqrt(3.0 * scale)
weights = np.random.uniform(-limit, limit, size=(2,2))
print(weights)
array([[0.11956818, 0.52710415],
       [0.25171784, 0.1099409 ]])
```

If you observe, the above two are not the same because of random number generators. Internally tensorflow uses the stateless random generator as below and if you observe, we got the same output.

```
tf.random.stateless_uniform(shape=(2,2),seed=[0, 0], minval=-limit, maxval=limit)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.7078647 ,  0.50461936],
       [ 0.73500216,  0.6633029 ]], dtype=float32)>
```

If you need to know more about internal implementation, you can check https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2b96f3662bd776e277f86997659e61046b56c315/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops_v2.py#L525

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can you please clarify the intuition behind your `limit`  (and `scale`) calculations?

Comment: Limit = sqrt(6/fanin + fanout) if fanin+fanout/2 >1 else, sqrt(3)

Comment: Thank you for re-writing the very thing I am trying to figure out. If you re-read my question this is exactly what I'm trying to understand. Re-reading this expression, unfortunately, doesn't make it any clearer for me =(.

Comment: I just wanted to note, that I'm gonna mark your answer as valid since in a way you did answer the question. But in reality, I was hoping for a bit more in-depth answers in regards to the calculations of the `limit`. Because that's what I don't understand yet. But for what it's worth, thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Jek, the details I found in the given link "Draws samples from a uniform distribution within [-limit, limit] where `limit` is `sqrt(6 / (fan_in + fan_out))` where `fan_in` is the number of input units in the weight tensor and `fan_out` is the number of output units in the weight tensor."
that may help you clarify things